# Switch case simple example not reflecting value in paragraph

Tags: javascript, html

I have got a simple switch case example in javascript. Though, the value in paragraph should be reflected as the third option in switch-case, it is showing nothing or blank paragraph. Pl, help!

```html
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<p id="para1"></p>
<script>
var i = 3; 
switch(i){
case 1: {
 document.getElementById('para1').value = "The value is one.";
 break;
}
case 2: {
 document.getElementById('para1').value = "The value is two.";
 break;
}
case 3: {
 document.getElementById('para1').value = "The value is three.";
 break;
}
default:{
 document.getElementById('para1').value = "The value is undefined."
}
}
</script> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: innerHTML not value

Answer (score 2):

`p` tag in not `input` element hence it doesn't have `value`. You should use `innerHTML` to set the value.

```
    <html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
    <p id="para1"></p>
    <script>
    var i = 3; 
    switch(i){
    case 1: {
     document.getElementById('para1').innerHTML = "The value is one.";
     break;
    }
    case 2: {
     document.getElementById('para1').innerHTML = "The value is two.";
     break;
    }
    case 3: {
     document.getElementById('para1').innerHTML = "The value is three.";
     break;
    }
    default:{
     document.getElementById('para1').innerHTML = "The value is undefined."
    }
    }
    </script> 
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use innerHTML instead of value:

```html
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<p id="para1"></p>
<script>
var i = 3; 
switch(i){
case 1: {
 document.getElementById('para1').innerHTML = "The value is one.";
 break;
}
case 2: {
 document.getElementById('para1').innerHTML = "The value is two.";
 break;
}
case 3: {
 document.getElementById('para1').innerHTML = "The value is three.";
 break;
}
default:{
 document.getElementById('para1').innerHTML = "The value is undefined."
}
}
</script> 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var i = 3; 
switch(i){
case 1: {
 document.getElementById('para1').innerHTML = "The value is one.";
 break;
}
case 2: {
 document.getElementById('para1').innerHTML = "The value is two.";
 break;
}
case 3: {
 document.getElementById('para1').innerHTML = "The value is three.";
 break;
}
default:{
 document.getElementById('para1').innerHTML = "The value is undefined."
}
}
```

```html
<p id="para1">test</p>
```

Comment: Please give an explanation. Just giving the answer doesn't help him/her.